# Server GTM: Is there any way to programmatically fetch server snippet (container config) using gtm API?

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side

I am trying to implement a working solution which programmatically creates the gtm container and runs the server setup script but cannot find a way to fetch the container config programmatically, just wondering if this can actually be done or not

Answer (score 0):

This is not mentioned in any document but what I have figured is:

It's a base64 encoded string of query parameter string e.g. `id=GTM-12345&env=1&auth=authcodestr` where

- `GTM-12345` is GTM public ID
- `1` is Live environment ID of the container
- `authcodestr` is Authorization code of the Live environment

[List Environments](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/environments/list) endpoint can be used to get ID and Authorization code of "live" environment.